# put div to the bottom of parent div

Tags: html, css

Code:

```
<div id="divPopUp" style="border: 2px solid gray; padding: 20px; width: 700px; background: white; height: 450px; ">
     <h1 style="text-align:center">Handsets</h1>

             <table>
               some table content 
             </table>  
    <div class="footerButtons" style="display: block;">
        <div style="float: left;">
            <input type="button"/>
        </div>
        <div style="float: left; margin-left: 207px;">
         <input type="button"/> <input type="button"/>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

I need to put div with class `"footerButtons"` to bottom of the main div. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

I have add `position:relative` to your main div and `position:absolute; bottom:10px` to your div with class `footerButtons` to make it always near the bottom like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/esez7aoL/1/) 
Hope this help!

```
<div id="divPopUp" style="border: 2px solid gray; padding: 20px; width: 700px; background: white; height: 450px; position:relative">
 <h1 style="text-align:center">Handsets</h1>

<table>some table content</table>
<div class="footerButtons" style="display: block; position:absolute; bottom:10px">
    <div style="float: left;">
        <input type="button" />
    </div>
    <div style="float: left; margin-left: 207px;">
        <input type="button" />
        <input type="button" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! that really help.

Comment: Please include the code you changed in the answer rather than just a link to an external site

Comment: Done and now upvoted, just a note though, you have spelt `relative` wrong in your fiddle and answer so the buttons are appearing at the bottom of the screen rather than the bottom of the div

Comment: oh thank for point out my mistake @Pete, i often typing wrong when i'm in an hurry